# What kind of character is this?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, inappropriate-content

I was reviewing [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604163/prevent-special-character-in-php-or-javascript) on SO, but the question was having a weird or say special kind of characters/lining over it. I dont understand from where it came ? although that question was removed after repeated down voting but I could take some screenshot of it. I still didn't understand from where they came from ? I checked that question in both Latest Firefox and Chrome browser but it was still there. following is the screen shot:
**Screenshot: 1**
[image]

**Screenshot 2**
[image]

Comment: Link to the question. (currently deleted -10k only) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604163/prevent-special-character-in-php-or-javascript

Answer (score 4):

Those are Unicode combining characters. They can be used to add accents to letters, but if you add more than one, they'll stack. They have been used (somewhat) legitimately in [the famous “parsing HTML with regex” answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454).